# C++/CLI: richTextBox to .txt with line breaks

Tags: file, c++-cli, command-line-interface, richtextbox

I'm trying to make a .txt file which saves data from richTextBox. I write in textbox for example:

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5ZO1.png)

But .txt contains:

test1test2test3

How can I do line breaks in this file? Here's my actual C++/CLI code:

```
    String ^ text = richTextBox1->Text;
    String ^ fileName = "lab.txt";
    StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter(fileName);
    sw->WriteLine(text);
    sw->Close();
```

Comment: RichTextBox uses non-conformal line-endings for histerical reasons.  You could use String^ text = richTextBox1->Text->Replace("\n", "\r\n") or use its [richTextBox1->SaveFile() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.savefile?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_RichTextBox_SaveFile_System_String_System_Windows_Forms_RichTextBoxStreamType_) so it does the job itself.

Comment: Replace method worked. Thank you so much :)